# CSS won't work with Django powered site

Tags: python, css, django, web

My CSS will not work when I run my site. Only the HTML displays. I have the right link. I'm confused as to what put in the MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, STATIC_ROOT, and STATIC_URL. Every site tell me something different. I'm not using the (**file**) directory. I the above mentioned setting refer to where the files are placed and where they are hosted. I'm not hosting my files anywhere as of right now. I'm in dev mode. I know django has something to view static files in dev mode but it won't work!!!! My questions: 1. Should I host my files? 2. What should i put in the above mentioned settings? Keep in mind I'm in dev mode!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give the link of your CSS in `STATIC_ROOT`.

In html Do: `{{ STATIC_URL }}/css` in link.

Comment: what do u mean by link of my css? where its located? or the url?

Comment: `STATIC_URL` is the location in the file system. `STATIC_ROOT` is the URL.

Comment: @user1957076: Header in HTML

Comment: If my files aren't hosted do i have a static_root?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the easiest way to do this is adding a folder `static` in the root of the project. Then look for and make settings attributes

`STATICFILES_DIRS = ('static',)` if you want you can make this absolute path(recommended by django)

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Since you're using the dev-server this should be able to work. Now to link to them in your templates what you have to do is

`<link href={{ STATIC_URL }}css/css.css>` for the css assuming the is a file project_root/static/css/css.css you basically do the same for javascript